# How to avoid logging certain event in logging module?

Tags: python, logging

Is it possible to set `logging` module in Python not to `log` one certain event?

I have this in my script:

```
 logging.basicConfig(filename='logging/logging_log.log',level=logging.INFO,format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
```

Which is `logging` automatically each connection. I do want to log each connection except one (trial version purposes).

So my log seems like this:

```
2016-03-02 16:08:20,519 INFO Starting new HTTP connection (1): noexample.com
2016-03-02 16:12:51,677 INFO Starting new HTTP connection (1): noexample.com
2016-03-02 16:12:52,045 INFO load_root> try: example.com
2016-03-02 16:12:52,046 INFO load_url example.com
2016-03-02 16:12:52,046 INFO Starting new HTTP connection (1):example.com
```

I want to keep every line except those with `noexample.com`.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement that using [logging filters](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/logging.html#filter-objects) like in [this example](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/412552-using-the-logging-module/)

```
class my_filter(logging.Filter):
    def __init__(self, name=None): pass
    def filter(self, rec):
        if 'noexample' in rec.msg:
            return False
```

Afterwards you need to call the handlers/loggers addFilter method

```
myhandler.addFilter(the_filter)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you tell me how to create the handler? logging.basicConfig(filename='logging/logging_log.log',level=logging.INFO,format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s') Is everything according to logging I have in my code.

Comment: You can also call addFilter on a logger instead.